# Neo4j foreign key

Tags: neo4j, key, constraints

I need your help with my school homework. We need to use neo4j as a database. We have 3 tables, researcher, kind, and publication tables.
Each publication has to have a kind and it will come from the kind table. If every researcher has a publication, it will come from the publication table. We need to add a foreign key. I couldn't find a source for this. How to add a foreign key in Neo4j?

Comment: What level is your school ... college, High School, etc.? This is a great assignment. I have college age grandchildren and they are not learning this.

Comment: i am a college student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign keys do not apply to a Graph Database like neo4j .

Instead, create one Node for each `publication`, create a Node for each `kind`, and create a Relationship between the respective Nodes. I.e.:

```
MERGE (pub1:Publication {name: "Neo4j Databases"})
MERGE (technical:Kind {name: "Technical"})
MERGE (pub1)-[:IS]->(technical)

MERGE (pub2:Publication {name: "Fried Chicken"})
MERGE (recipe:Kind {name: "Recipe"})
MERGE (pub2)-[:IS]->(recipe)
```